# Bad state: Mock method was not called within `when()`. Was a real method called?

Tags: dart, flutter, mockito, flutter-test

I'm trying to make a mock of an `httpRequest` in flutter using mockito.

Here I define a global http client:

```dart
library utgard.globals;

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

http.Client httpClient = http.Client();
```

Then I replace in integration testing:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:utgard/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

import 'package:utgard/main.dart' as app;

class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

void main() {
  final MockClient client = MockClient();
  globals.httpClient = client;

  enableFlutterDriverExtension();

  app.main();
}
```

Then I try to use `when` of mockito:

```dart
test('login with correct password', () async {
      final client = MockClient();

      when(globals.httpClient.post('http://www.google.com'))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('{"title": "Test"}', 200));

      await driver.enterText('000000');
      await driver.tap(loginContinuePasswordButton);
    });
```

But I receive the following error:

> Bad state: Mock method was not called within `when()`. Was a real method called?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This issue may happen when you implement a method you want to mock instead of letting Mockito do that.

This code below will return `Bad state: Mock method was not called within when(). Was a real method called?`:

```dart
class MockFirebaseAuth extends Mock implements FirebaseAuth {
  FirebaseUser _currentUser;

  MockFirebaseAuth(this._currentUser);

  // This method causes the issue.
  Future<FirebaseUser> currentUser() async {
    return _currentUser;
  }
}

final user = MockFirebaseUser();
final mockFirebaseAuth = MockFirebaseAuth(user);

// Will throw `Bad state: Mock method was not called within `when()`. Was a real method called?`
when(mockFirebaseAuth.currentUser())
    .thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(user));
```

What do you want instead is:

```dart
class MockFirebaseAuth extends Mock implements FirebaseAuth {}

final user = MockFirebaseUser();
final mockFirebaseAuth = MockFirebaseAuth();

// Will work as expected
when(mockFirebaseAuth.currentUser())
    .thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(user));
```

Also this issue happens **when you try to call `when()` on a non-mock sublass**:

```dart
class MyClass {
  String doSomething() {
    return 'test';
  }
}

final myClassInstance = MyClass();

// Will throw `Bad state: Mock method was not called within `when()`. Was a real method called?`
when(myClassInstance.doSomething())
    .thenReturn((_) => 'mockedValue');
```

Comment: In my case I want to mock `toString()` so I can see the errors more clearly, not just the class names, but `toString()` is already defined from `Mock` itself.

Comment: One more case if you try to mock mixin method.

Answer (score 3):

There is one more possibility. If this happens to your mock object, then probably it may be outdated. In this case, try regenerating your mock objects by using

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Answer (score 0):

please declare `resetMocktailState()` in teardown or at the end of setup, so the test cases should not affect later test cases.

Answer (score -2):

The solution I found was to define the mock in *test_driver/app.dart* and call the `runApp` function after that, this way you can apply the mock even with flutter integration testing:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:utgard/business/config/globals.dart';
import 'package:utgard/main.dart' as app;

class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

void main() {
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();

  final MockClient client = MockClient();
  // make your mocks here
  httpClient = client;

  runApp(app.MyApp());
}
```

Since it can become a huge code to mock all the requests there you can make a separate function in order to better organize the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:utgard/business/config/globals.dart';
import 'package:utgard/main.dart' as app;

class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

void main() {
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();

  final MockClient client = MockClient();
  makeMock();
  httpClient = client;

  runApp(app.MyApp());
}
```